# How to get List of All messaging Apps from my app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, messaging

[image]Presently I am using MFMessageComposeViewController to send messages.
But now i want to provide an option like via some other Apps like Skype, whats Apps etc.
Is there any Public API to get list those Apps including  App icon and App name and how to redirect to those Apps.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Apps work in a Sandboxed mode so don't know about other apps on the device. Skype, whats app etc have special agreements with Apple to be able to certain things that apps normally can't do.

Comment: then how sme  Apps providing Option like popover in ipad to send msg

Comment: @siva yeah, following your update. That screenshot is a `UIActivityViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do works the other way around.

You will never be able to find out what apps the user has on a device.

I assume you are talking about the options in a `UIActivityViewController`?

In that case, what you do is provide content for activity view controller (text, image, url, etc...) and the activity view controller will then present any apps that can deal with the content you have provided.

For instance, if you provide an image you'll get camera roll, email, Facebook, etc.

If you provide text and image you'll get email, messages, etc...

If you provide text under 140 chars you'll get twitter. If it's over 140 chars you won't get twitter.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply,i don’t know UIActivityViewController. So I have to use UIActivityViewController instead of MFMessageComposeViewController.

Comment: `UIActivityViewController` will pop up a list of options (like when you press share in photos). MFMessageComposeViewController is for emails only. The user can still access the email compose view if you provide them with a `UIActivityViewController` and they press email, but they'll also have Messages, Facebook, Twitter, etc...

Comment: k,if suppose the user installed Skype and shalll i get those Apps in this list like my above screen shot

Comment: No idea, it depends if Skype has registered its app as accepting the information you have provided. You should be able to google what the criteria are though.

Comment: This might be useful to you. http://software.techassistbox.com/skype-message-sharing_4437952.html

Comment: k,will implement it. I am not only talking about skype, All other Apps which are in device That Allowed to send msgs.

Comment: Why the down vote? On a correct and accepted answer?

Comment: I was Upvoted And Accpeted.also I have some doubt my ipad has facebook App but i am ot getting it in UIActivityViewController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58154/discussion-between-fogmeister-and-siva).